# Text from file and checkbox in JScrollPane swings

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to have textarea and checkbox in a scroll pane in swings. My code looks like:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
public class ScrollBar {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ScrollBar s = new ScrollBar();
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea ();
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setAlignmentX(10);
        panel.setAlignmentY(10);
        panel.setSize(330, 240);        
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(100,0));     
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader("license.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputFile);
        textArea.read(br, null);
        panel.add(textArea);
        JCheckBox j = new JCheckBox("I accept");
        panel.add(j);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (panel, 
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.setTitle("License");
        frame.setSize(430,270); 
        frame.setVisible(true);  
    }
}
```

It is working fine but I am getting I accept checkbox after many lines when text ends.

output screen.

[image]

Can anyone please help me and let me know how can I get rid of the spaces.

Comment: You are creating a gridlayout with 100 rows, is this what you really want?

Comment: Do you really need both in the scroll pane? Wouldn't it be better to just have the text area in its own scroll pane and the check box laid out (maybe) in the south position, under the scroll pane?

Comment: that helps in reading the whole file before clicking checkbox.

Comment: I think I should use GridBagLayout as I need uneven spacing of rows\columns and Gridlayout gives a rectangular layout with uniform size layouts.

Answer (score 2):

In pseudo code

1. Create Panel. Set to BorderLayout
2. Wrap text area in scroll pane and add scroll panel to CENTER
3. Add checkbox to south